# Fila del formulario no se acomoda al diseño

Tags: bootstrap-3

Necesito ayuda en acomodar una de las filas del formulario, no se muestra adecuadamente. Específicamente la correspondiente a **Puerto de destino**, queda pegada a las demás filas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que genera la vista del formulario:

```
{% form_theme form  'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">{{ form_label(form.numeroContenedor) }}</div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">{{ form_label(form.bl) }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">{{ form_widget(form.numeroContenedor) }}</div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">{{ form_widget(form.bl) }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">{{ form_errors(form.numeroContenedor) }}</div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">{{ form_errors(form.bl) }}</div>
        </div> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">{{ form_label(form.puertoDestino)}}</div>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">{{ form_widget(form.puertoDestino)}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">{{ form_errors(form.puertoDestino)}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">{{ form_label(form.fechaCargaEstado) }}</div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">{{ form_label(form.fechaEntradaPuerto) }}</div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">{{ form_label(form.fechaCargaPuerto) }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    {{ form_widget(form.fechaCargaEstado) }}
                    <label class="input-group-btn" for="menaje_datosMenaje_fechaCargaEstado">
                        <span class="btn btn-default">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>    

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    {{ form_widget(form.fechaEntradaPuerto) }}
                    <label class="input-group-btn" for="menaje_datosMenaje_fechaEntradaPuerto">
                        <span class="btn btn-default">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    {{ form_widget(form.fechaCargaPuerto) }}
                    <label class="input-group-btn" for="menaje_datosMenaje_fechaCargaPuerto">
                        <span class="btn btn-default">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">{{ form_errors(form.fechaCargaEstado) }}</div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">{{ form_errors(form.fechaEntradaPuerto) }}</div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">{{ form_errors(form.fechaCargaPuerto) }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".js-datepicker").datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            endDate: '0d',
            autoclose: true,
            forceParse: true,
            inmediateUpdates: true,
            keyboardNavigation: true,
            language: 'es',
            maxViewMode: 'years',
            minViewMode: 'day',
            orientation: 'right',
            startView: 'days',
            title: "",
            weekStart: 1
        }).on('show', function () {
            var zIndexModal = $('#modalCrearEstructura').css('z-index');
            $(document).find('.datepicker').css('z-index', zIndexModal + 1);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Dale margen superior e inferior a el div.row en el que esta contenido

Comment: el problema es que en el label tienes class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" y en el input class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" si quieres que el input ocupe toda la columna ponlo en 12 y el label tambien en 12 agrega en el "row" la clase "form-group" para que le de un margin entre cada fila